# Arrayformula for Google Sheets doesn't work as before

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Some week ago, an array formula I use in Google Sheets stopped working correctly:

```
=arrayformula(if(row(A:A)=1,"Convert Type",if(len(A:A)=0,iferror(1/0),iferror(vlookup(C:C,'Sheet2'!$A$2:$B,2,FALSE),"Error"))))
```

This formula is in Sheet1 column B1, in the frozen first row. What it is supposed to do is to take the values from Sheet1 column C, compare the values from Sheet2 column A, and insert the values in Sheet1 column B for those corresponding in Sheet2 column B (from Type1 to Type2). If there is a mismatch between the possibilities in Sheet2 column A and Sheet1 column C, the new value in Sheet1 column B will be 'Error.' The formula stops when there is nothing in Sheet1 column A (Timestamp).

Now, for some reason, all the values in Sheet1 column B are set to 'Error.' Something similar happened before when Google made a back-end update, but this time I can't figure out what I am supposed to change. Any ideas?

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/135Mc3t96_HzenR90sgxvi8C55KMfeliNIYbszjhK1Y0/edit?usp=drivesdk)

*Edit: made the text clearer and added a link with example.*

Comment: OK, thanks for reminding me. I'll set up an example later and update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding a extra space in your formula updates the formula to correct values and I'm unable to find the source of the error.

Regardless, the formula was unnecessarily complicated and I simplified it a bit to it's core bone version. Try this instead:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Convert Type";VLOOKUP(C2:INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(C:C)),Sheet2!A:B,2,0)})
```

Comment: Thanks, the space solved it (as reflected on the example). Thanks for the sleeker formula as well.

Comment: The original sheet has space in its name and I forgot to remove the apostrophes. Although there are no problems now in the example I made, the original (which I cannot share) still has the problem. I'll have to figure out what else might be causing it. The new formula solves it though (without having 'Error' as message, but 'N/A'), so thanks again.